# Does Microsoft use Visual Studio to work on Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

The title pretty much asks the question: Does Microsoft use Visual Studio to work on Visual Studio? Just out of random curiosity I was wondering this, if anyone knows, I would appreciate an answer!

Comment: The answer is so obvious, so I wonder why you are asking. Microsoft is famous for dog fooding their own products inside the firm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Apple uses XCode to develop their OS and XCode, so does Microsoft with Visual Studio. Not really a programming related question though.